# sqlite3_prepare_v2 returning 21 & "could not prepare statemnt: out of memory"

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, storing-data

I am getting these errors, everything is in here. All I am doing is creating a .db file with a path specified by Xcode, and then creating a table with the shown values as columns. I then try to go ahead and populate the table but receive the errors above in the title (seems as though these are what are causing my headaches). If someone could shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#import "Email.h"

@implementation Email

@synthesize to, cc, bcc, fromName, fromEmail, headers, datetime, subject, body, folder, state, attachments;

-(void)StoreEmail:(Email *)email{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] 
    initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
    @"contacts2.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB2) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS2 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FROM TEXT, NAME TEXT, SUBJECT TEXT, BODY TEXT, ATTACHMENTS TEXT, HEADERS TEXT, DATETIME TEXT, FOLDER TEXT, STATE TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB2, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"path" message:@"failed to create table" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }
            sqlite3_close(contactDB2);
        } 
        else 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"path" message:@"failed to open/create database" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"path" message:databasePath delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB2) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"This is what open returns %d", sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB2));
        //NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS2 (from, name, subject, body, attachments, headers, datetime, folder, state) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", email.fromEmail, email.fromName, email.subject, email.body, email.attachments, email.headers, email.datetime, email.folder, email.state];
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS2 (from, name) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\")", email.fromEmail, email.fromName];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB2, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        NSLog(@"could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        //NSLog(@"%d", sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB2, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL));
        if (sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"2");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"path" message:@"email added" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

        } 
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"%d", sqlite3_step(statement));
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"path" message:@"failed to add email" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB2);
    }
}
```